# Sums of entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two entire, non-surjective, functions. This means

$$
A(z)=e^{f(z)}+c_1
$$
and
$$
  B(z)=e^{g(z)}+c_2
$$
for some entire functions $f$ and $g$, and some complex constants $c_1$ and $c_2$.

When is the sum $A(z)+B(z)$ an surjective entire function? More precisely, is there any condition on $f$ and $g$. Clearly the sum may fail to be surjective, for example when $f(z)=g(z)+c$. But also can be surjective, for example when $f(z)=2g(z)$. A naive conjecture would be that the sum is surjective as long as $f-g$ is not constant. Is that actually true?

Answer (score 0):

> $A(z)+B(z)=2\cos (f(z))+c_1+c_2$ if $g(z)=-f(z)$.
> Now this is surjective as long as $f(z)$ itself is surjective like a polynomial, sine function or cosine function. In general, the sum function  $A(z)+B(z)$ is surjective iff $g(z)=-f(z)$ and $f(z)\neq h(e^z)$ for some entire $h$.